# Are a CASE statement and a DECODE equivalent?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

It seems like the simple CASE expression and the DECODE function are equivalent and that the results returned by them should be identical. Are they?

The documentation has the following to say about the [simple CASE expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#CHDJCCGI):

> The simple CASE expression returns the first result for which
>   selector_value matches selector. Remaining expressions are not
>   evaluated. If no selector_value matches selector, the CASE expression
>   returns else_result if it exists and NULL otherwise.

Comparing this to the [DECODE function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions049.htm#SQLRF00631), the descriptions seem to be identical.

> DECODE compares expr to each search value one by one. If expr is equal
>   to a search, then Oracle Database returns the corresponding result. If
>   no match is found, then Oracle returns default. If default is omitted,
>   then Oracle returns null.

As the [searched CASE expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS281) can be equivalent to the simple, this could be construed to be the same as well.

These three statements all seem to return the same result, 0.

```
select case 1 when 2 then null else 0 end as simple_case
     , case when 1 = 2 then null else 0 end as searched_case
     , decode(1, 2, null, 0) as decode
  from dual
```

Do the simple CASE expression and the DECODE function (and in specific circumstances the searched CASE expression) always return the same result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ben has written a lengthy answer on the differences between DECODE and CASE. He demonstrates that DECODE and CASE may return different datatypes for apparently the same set of values without properly explaining why this happens.

DECODE() is quite prescriptive: it is always the datatype of the first *result* parameter. Oracle applies implicit conversion to all the other result parameters.  It will throw an  error ,  if (say) the first result parameter is numeric and the default value is a date.

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

This is described in the documentation: [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions049.htm#i1017437).

In the first scenario the first result parameter is NULL, which Oracle decides to treat as VARCHAR2.  If we change it so that the first result parameter is numeric and the default value is null the DECODE() statement will return a NUMBER; a DUMP() proves that this is so.

Whereas CASE insists that all the returned values have the same datatype, and will throw a compilation error if this is not the case.  It won't apply implicit conversion.  This is also covered in the documentation. [Read it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm#sthref1848).

The difference boils down to this.  The following DECODE statement will run, the CASE statement won't:

```
select decode(1, 1, 1, '1') from dual;

select case 1 when 1 then 1 else '1' end from dual;
```

[Obligatory SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9869c/1)

Comment: Less is often more regarding answers at SO.

Answer (score 25):

Short answer, no.

The slightly longer answer is nearly.

It only *appears* that the result obtained from each statement is identical. If we use the [DUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions055.htm#SQLRF00635) function to evaluate the data types returned you'll see what I mean:

```
SQL> select dump(case 1 when 2 then null else 0 end) as simple_case
  2       , dump(case when 1 = 2 then null else 0 end) as searched_case
  3       , dump(decode(1, 2, null, 0)) as decode
  4    from dual;

SIMPLE_CASE        SEARCHED_CASE      DECODE
------------------ ------------------ -----------------
Typ=2 Len=1: 128   Typ=2 Len=1: 128   Typ=1 Len=1: 48
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca3d7/7)

You can see that the data type of the DECODE is 1, whereas the two CASE statements "return" a data type of 2. Using Oracle's [Data Type Summary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG), DECODE is returning a VARCHAR2 (data type 1) whereas the CASE statements are "returning" numbers (data type 2).

I assume this occurs because, as the names suggest, DECODE is a *function* and CASE isn't, which implies they have been implemented differently internally. There's no real way to prove this.

You might think that this doesn't really affect anything. If you need it to be a number Oracle will implicitly convert the character to a number under the [implicit conversion rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i53062), right? This isn't true either, it [won't work in a UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12057748/458741) as the data types *have* to be identical; Oracle won't do any implicit conversion to make things easy for you. Secondly, here's what Oracle says about implicit conversion:

> Oracle recommends that you specify explicit conversions, rather than rely on implicit or automatic conversions, for these reasons:
>
> - SQL statements are easier to understand when you use explicit data type conversion functions.
> - Implicit data type conversion can have a negative impact on    performance, especially if the data type of a column value is converted to that of a constant rather than the other way around.
> - Implicit conversion depends on the context in which it occurs and may not work the same way in every case. For example, implicit conversion from a datetime value to a VARCHAR2 value may return an unexpected year depending on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
>     parameter.
> - Algorithms for implicit conversion are subject to change across software releases and among Oracle products. Behavior of explicit conversions is more predictable.

That's not a pretty list; but the penultimate point brings me nicely on to dates. If we take the previous query and convert it into one that uses a date instead:

```
select case sysdate when trunc(sysdate) then null 
                    else sysdate 
       end as simple_case
     , case when sysdate = trunc(sysdate) then null 
            else sysdate 
       end as searched_case
     , decode(sysdate, trunc(sysdate), null, sysdate) as decode
  from dual;
```

Once again, using DUMP on this query the CASE statements return data type 12, a DATE. The DECODE has converted `sysdate` into a VARCHAR2.

```
SQL> select dump(case sysdate when trunc(sysdate) then null
  2                           else sysdate
  3              end) as simple_case
  4       , dump(case when sysdate = trunc(sysdate) then null
  5                   else sysdate
  6              end) as searched_case
  7       , dump(decode(sysdate, trunc(sysdate), null, sysdate)) as decode
  8    from dual;

SIMPLE_CASE          
---------------------------------- 
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,112,12,4,22,18,7 
SEARCHED_CASE
---------------------------------- 
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,112,12,4,22,18,7
DECODE
---------------------------------- 
Typ=1 Len=19: 50,48,49,50,45,49,50,45,48,52,32,50,49,58,49,55,58,48,54
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca3d7/9)

Note (in the SQL Fiddle) that the DATE has been converted into a character using the sessions [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams145.htm#REFRN10119).

Having a date that's been implicitly converted into a VARCHAR2 can cause problems. If you're intending to use [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129), to convert your date into a character, your query will break where you're not expecting it.

```
SQL> select to_char( decode( sysdate
  2                         , trunc(sysdate), null
  3                         , sysdate )
  4                 , 'yyyy-mm-dd') as to_char
  5    from dual;
select to_char( decode( sysdate
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca3d7/23)

Equally, date arithmetic no longer works:

```
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select decode(sysdate, trunc(sysdate), null, sysdate) + 1 as decode
  2    from dual;
select decode(sysdate, trunc(sysdate), null, sysdate) + 1 as decode
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca3d7/22)

Interestingly DECODE only converts the expression to a VARCHAR2 if one of the possible results is NULL. If the default value is NULL then this doesn't happen. For instance:

```
SQL> select decode(sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, null) as decode
  2    from dual;

DECODE
-------------------
2012-12-04 21:18:32

SQL> select dump(decode(sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, null)) as decode
  2    from dual;

DECODE
------------------------------------------    
Typ=13 Len=8: 220,7,12,4,21,18,32,0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca3d7/17)

Note that the DECODE has returned a data type of 13. This isn't documented but is, I assume, a type of date as date arithmetic etc. works.

In short, avoid DECODE if you possibly can; you might not necessarily get the data types you're expecting. To [quote Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1243867216406):

> Decode is somewhat obscure -- CASE is very very clear. Things that are
>   easy to do in decode are easy to do in CASE, things that are hard or
>   near impossible to do with decode are easy to do in CASE. CASE, logic
>   wise, wins hands down.

---

Just to be complete there are two *functional* differences between DECODE and CASE.

1. DECODE cannot be used within PL/SQL.
2. CASE cannot be used to compare nulls directly

   ```
   SQL> select case null when null then null else 1 end as case1
     2        , case when null is null then null else 1 end as case2
     3        , decode(null, null, null, 1) as decode
     4    from dual
     5         ;

        CASE1      CASE2 DECODE
   ---------- ---------- ------
            1
   ```

   [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca3d7/21)

Comment: +1 and I wish I could +5 - Now that's what I call a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Justin, high praise from you! I've been thinking about this for a month since I got caught badly so I've had enough time to formulate what I wanted to write :-).

Comment: +1 from me as well. I would have sworn they are identical (although I do prefer CASE for the same reasons as Tom Kyte does).

Comment: @JustinCave - Comprehensive but alas not complete

Answer (score -3):

I know i am too late but posting here because if someone search for that hopefully it could help.
I have created a MsSql script for the same-

```
Declare @Var varchar(399)='DECODE(MyColumnName,''A'',''Auto'',''M'',''Manual'')'

Begin
Declare @Count int, @Counter int=1
Declare @TempTable table (ID int identity(1,1),Items varchar(500))
Declare @SqlText varchar(max)
Select @Var=Replace(Replace(@Var,'DECODE(',''),')','')

Insert Into @TempTable
Select * FROM [dbo].[Split] ( @Var ,',')
--Select * from @TempTable
Select @Count=Count(ID) from @TempTable

While(@Counter<=@Count)
Begin
    If(@Counter=1)
    Begin
    Select @SqlText='Case ' +Items from @TempTable Where ID=1
    End

    Else If(@Counter=@Count)
    Begin
    Select @SqlText+=' Then ' +Items +' End' from @TempTable Where ID=@Counter 
    End

    Else If(@Counter%2=0)
    Begin
    Select @SqlText +=' When ' +Items from @TempTable Where ID=@Counter
    End

    Else If(@Counter%2=1)
    Begin
    Select @SqlText +=' Then ' +Items from @TempTable Where ID=@Counter
    End

    Set @Counter+=1
End

Select @SqlText SqlServerCaseStatement
End
```

I used Split function in above script, if you need that function you can refer Romil's answer - [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: Hi, thank you but I think you've completely missed the point of the question... and it's for Oracle not SQL Server...