# if-elseif-else 'condition' in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering if there if possibility to achieve some thing like

'if-elseif-else'  condition , i know there is a 'case-when-then-else' but it checks only one condition at a time (if i understand it correctly). How can i achieve if-elseif-else scenario in Oracle sql

Comment: Nesting CASE statements is one option. I'm not familiar enough with Oracle to know if there's a better way though.

Comment: What do you mean by _it checks only one condition at a time_  As case statement should help..if not then use decode but it only does equality checks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386881/using-if-else-in-oracle

Comment: If any of the below are not working, could you add an example of this in the if-then-elseif type?

Answer (score 20):

You can use if/else using case statements like this.

```
SELECT ename, CASE WHEN sal = 1000 THEN 'Minimum wage'
                   WHEN sal > 1000 THEN 'Over paid'
                   ELSE 'Under paid'
              END AS "Salary Status"
FROM   emp;
```

Answer (score 1):

> i know there is a 'case-when-then-else' but it checks only one
>   condition at a time

What you are describing is a SIMPLE case. Oracle has two case types: SIMPLE and SEARCHED (see here for more info http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

SIMPLE

```
case A
  when 1 then 'foo'
  when 2 then 'bar'
  else ..
end
```

SEARCHED

```
case
  when A=1 and B='A' then 'foo'
  when D + C =1 and B !='A' then 'Bar'
  else ..
end
```

you probably want to use a searched case. You can use them in PL/SQL or SQL. eg in SQL

```
select ..
  from table
 where case
         when A=1 and B='A' then 'foo'
         when D + C =1 and B !='A' then 'Bar'
         else ..
       end = 'foo'
```

Comment: I had used some thing like this but it is not working

Comment: yes i need searched case

Answer (score 0):

Look out for "Decode in Oracle"

```
decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )
```

It is similar to "if-elseif-else"

Refer: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php

**NOTE:** It does only equality checks..