# Oracle rename partition if exists

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, partition

I need to create a statement that can be run to rename a partition only if specific partition name exists and if not then continue on to execute other code.

```
basic command  = ALTER TABLE TEST RENAME PARTITION P1 TO P2:
```

I have looked at the following but have not come up with a solution

- [Using IF ELSE in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386881/using-if-else-in-oracle)
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm

Comment: Why so you like to rename a partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether the partition exists within the table USER_TAB_PARTITIONS:

```
DECLARE
  v_p1_exists AS NUMBER;
  v_p2_exists AS NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_p1_exists
    FROM user_tab_partitions
   WHERE table_name = 'TEST'
     AND partition_name = 'P1';
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_p2_exists
    FROM user_tab_partitions
   WHERE table_name = 'TEST'
     AND partition_name = 'P2';
   IF (v_p1_exists <> 0) AND (v_p2_exists = 0) THEN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST RENAME PARTITION P1 TO P2';
   END;
END;
```

Comment: Just a note: (Like mine) this procedure will raise an exception if a partition `P2` already exist.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I depends on your requirements but a basic procedure would be this one:

```
DECLARE
    PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -2149); 
BEGIN

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST RENAME PARTITION P1 TO P2';
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN NULL;
    END;

    ... ohter commands
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to enclose ALTER TABLE into its own BEGIN-END block, with appropriate exception handling section. Mine is kind of *stupid* (WHEN OTHERS, eh?); feel free to rewrite it to be meaningful - it is just to show *how* to do it.

So: if ALTER TABLE fails, it'll raise some error; it'll be captured, handled, and code will continue its execution.

```
begin
  begin
    execute immediate 'alter table test rename partition p1 to p2';
  exception
    when others then 
      -- ignore errors
      null;
  end;

  -- continue to execute other code
  ...
end;
```