# convert letter to number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a student table, one of its column contains the grade obtained by student(eg, A,B,C...). I need to assign a number to every grade (eg, A->10, B->8, C->6 ...)

I am new to sql and I am not getting any idea on how to do it.
I tried one method which I found online:

```
select letter_grade, case when 'A' then 4 end as lettergrade from students;
```

But its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using IF ELSE in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386881/using-if-else-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Oracle solution (which will not work in other SQL dialects, because it uses an Oracle proprietary function) is to use `decode()`. This function compares the first argument to the second, forth, sixth etc. and when it finds a match, it returns the argument immediately following the match. If no match is found, it returns the default entered as the last argument.

```
select student_id, letter_grade,
       decode(letter_grade, 'A', 10, 'B', 8, 'C', 6, 'D', 4, 0) as numeric_grade
from   students
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track:

```
SELECT
    letter_grade,
    CASE letter_grade WHEN 'A' THEN 10
                      WHEN 'B' THEN 8
                      WHEN 'C' THEN 6
                      WHEN 'D' THEN 4
                      ELSE 0 END AS number_grade
FROM students;
```