# Substitute numeric pattern values into desired word pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, substitution

I have a column in a table which usually is filled with 10 or 11 values. I need to make a report and need to transform this 10 value into 'Class1' and 11 into 'Class2' texts and null in any other case.

I made it in the past but forget to save it as a snippet.

Comment: can you give an input/output example of what you want?  You want to change the number 10 into the string 'Class1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`case`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm) is probably the cleanest solution:

```
select case my_column
    when 10 then 'Class1'
    when 11 then 'Class2'
    else null
    end
from my_table;
```

Although having said that, having the text equivalent stored in a table is probably more reliable generally, so you can just join to it.

Comment: Also vaguely related, or at least interesting: [Are a CASE statement and a DECODE equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13712763/266304)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE`, or `DECODE`  and `NVL` for the null value, or a `CASE`.

Comment: But I wonder what keywords you try when looking up on the internet for not finding this. Because even *oracke substitue string* redirects directly to the replace function.