# ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected char got number

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to execute the query below I get the error:

> ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected char got number

```
select (case when upper (TEXT) <> lower (TEXT) then 'INVALID'
             else sum(TEXT)
        end) 
  from CLASS 
 where SECTION = 'SEVENTH'
```

The query works fine when I remove SUM in ELSE condition> But I need to SUM the Text to achieve the expected result.

Comment: How do you want to sum text...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are a CASE statement and a DECODE equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712763/are-a-case-statement-and-a-decode-equivalent)

Comment: The accepted answer (and the other) explains the problem. Your then statements in a CASE must be the same datatype.

Comment: It looks like you're testing to see whether text is a number or not, by testing whether upper(text) = lower(text). It's not really foolproof. You also need to GROUP BY a value if you might have both numeric and non-numeric values in there. you'd do well to show us the data and what output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sum a character value and all the returned values in a CASE statement [*must* be the same datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712763/are-a-case-statement-and-a-decode-equivalent).

If you transform your SUM to a character using TO_CHAR() this still won't work as you're not grouping correctly, see this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02f52/4).

The easiest way to do this would be to return a 0 rather than `'INVALID'`, sum over the entire case statement and change this back to `'INVALID'` if it's 0. It's not quite the same... don't store numbers in character columns?

```
select case when a = 0 then 'INVALID'
            else to_char(a)
       end
  from ( select sum( case when upper(txt) <> lower(txt) then 0
                          else to_number(txt)
                     end ) as a
           from class )
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02f52/7) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't `SUM` text, right? That's why it works well when you remove the operation from the `CASE`. Have you tried using `to_number` on the value you're trying to sum?

Comment: [This will not work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02f52/1) as a CASE needs to return only one datatype.