# Oracle differences using Quotes in case statement and insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I encountered this scenario where the insert based on '' on number column works fine while the case statement gives different error. 
"inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

I have gone through some of the explanation given here ([ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected char got number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015044/ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-char-got-number) ) and [Oracle SQL CASE WHEN ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678672/oracle-sql-case-when-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-char-got-number)  and I understand that I need to use it without quotes but I wanted to understand the behavior of case statement. SQL server does not behave like this, but why only oracle. Is this oracle default behavior with case statement.

If I create and insert values, I can do it without any error.

```
create table testtbl (name varchar2(50), id number(10,2)); 

insert into testtbl values ('abc', '123'); 
insert into testtbl values ('test', '200');
```

When I try to update the column using case statement I am getting this error. I can use to_number or remove the quotes to avoid this error but wanted to understand why it happens with quotes when the column given in the else statement is number itself. Doesn't implicit conversion exist in Oracle?

```
update testtbl 
set id = case when name = 'abc' then '5000' else id end;
```

Comment: There might be some kind of implicit conversion in Oracle (there certainly is on MySQL and a few other databases), but even so you should not be relying on it.  Instead, _always_ make sure that all branches of a `CASE` expression have the same type.

Comment: Your code should work, unless `'5000'` cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah I will make sure not to rely on implicit conversion while using this statement

Comment: @Gordon..Yeah the same statement works in MS SQL for int data type, while for Oracle I have to remove quotes as it may be converted to char as per oracle implicit conversion documentation.. without quotes it works fine as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't implicit conversion exist in Oracle?

It does. See documentation eg [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm).

> Is this oracle default behavior with case statement.

Yes. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

*For both simple and searched CASE expressions, all of the return_exprs must either have the same datatype (CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2, NUMBER, BINARY_FLOAT, or BINARY_DOUBLE) or must all have a numeric datatype.*

Comment: Thank You @Stefan this was helpful. I saw the table on possible conversions of a number to different data types with implicit conversion, so I guess it is always good to avoid quotes while using update in Oracle.

Comment: You are welcome!  Prefer explicit conversions (Oracle recommend this - see documentation link in the answer.)