# Oracle Subselect in NVL (Group By required)

Tags: oracle, group-by, subquery, nvl, ora-00937

I'm facing a problem in Oracle.
I had a SQL where some values were fixed. Now I started replacing them with values from a parameter-table. Some of these fixed values where in a NVL().

Simply said my statement is like this.

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(t.datefield), to_date('01011900','DDMMYYYY'))
FROM table t;
```

That works fine.

Now I want to replace the fixed date to a date from my parameter-table with a subselect, which doesn't work at all.

```
// Works
SELECT NVL(MAX(NULL), 'hello') FROM DUAL;

// Doesn't work
SELECT NVL(MAX(NULL), (SELECT 'hello' FROM DUAL)) FROM DUAL;
```

The error is:

```
ORA-00937: .... "not a single-group group function"
```

I have no idea how to group by a subselect.

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group by a sub-select. However, in order to achieve this your sub-select is only going to be able to return one row. So, change it into a Cartesian join and group by that.

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(NULL), str) 
  FROM DUAL
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 'hello' as str FROM DUAL )
 GROUP BY STR
```

More generally every column that is not included in an aggregate function *must* be included in the GROUP BY. Plus [`NVL()` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13712763/458741); use `COALESCE()` or `CASE` instead.

Comment: Excellent- Thanks a million! I don't know why I didn't think that way around. With the Nvl/Coalesce problem you are absolutly right, I was just using the given code.