# Oracle equivalent of NVL for number datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the Oracle equivalent of NVL for number datatypes?

This works since the datatype is VARCHAR:

```
    select nvl(enrol.OUAC_APPLNO, 'blank') Invalid_OUAC_APPLNO
```

But this doesn't work since the datatype is NUMBER:

```
    select nvl(enrol.ouac_type_id, 'blank') REGTYP
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `NVL`. You can't do `select 42 from dual union select 'Arthur' from dual` either. A column must have the same datatype in each and every row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent and no Oracle functions will accept this ([apart from `DECODE()` but don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13712763/458741)); you're going to have to convert your number to a character:

```
select nvl(cast(enrol.OUAC_APPLNO as varchar2(10)), 'blank')
```

You may need to change the number of characters you're converting to as appropriate.

However, I don't know why you're doing this at all. By definition a NULL implies non-existence. If you want to display `blank` in order to confer non-existence this is something that you should be doing with your presentation layer rather than the database.

Comment: Thanks... I'm exporting the query results as Excel and giving the spreadsheet to the end users, and I'd rather not manipulate the data in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

it wont work because oracle wants every row should be in the same type otherwise you cannot run functions on that column, you have cast ouac_type_id to be varchar as below;

```
select nvl(cast(enrol.OUAC_APPLNO as varchar2(10)), 'blank') REGTYP
```

Comment: This is also right, but I can't seem to mark two answers as correct.

Answer (score 0):

select nvl(TO_CHAR(enrol.OUAC_APPLNO), 'blank') REGTYP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks