# Select row or default row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below columns in my table **NAMES**:

```
|-------------|
|    NAMES    |
|-------------|
| NAME | LANG |
|-------------|
```

There are 3 types of records: lang = **'en'**, lang = **'ua'** and lang = **chr(0)** (default lang)

Now I should select names by lang with next condition:

1. If I select by lang and record for this lang exists then it should
   be returned
2. If I select by lang and record for this lang is absent then default
   NAME should be returned (where lang = chr(0))

I generated next query for this, but it looks awful

```
SELECT 
   NAME 
FROM NAMES WHERE 
   LANG = :lang 
   OR (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE LANG = :lang) AND LANG = chr(0))
```

Is there any better way to implement this? (Oracle DB is used)

**Sample data:**
1)

```
|--------------|
|    NAMES     |
|--------------|
| NAME | LANG  |
|--------------|
| Ivan |  ua   |
| Kris | chr(0)|
|--------------|
```

Search by **en** returns **Kris**

2)

```
|--------------|
|    NAMES     |
|--------------|
| NAME | LANG  |
|--------------|
| Ivan |  ua   |
| Kris | chr(0)|
| Mike |  en   |
|--------------|
```

Search by **en** returns **Mike**

3)

```
|--------------|
|    NAMES     |
|--------------|
| NAME | LANG  |
|--------------|
| Ivan |  ua   |
|--------------|
```

Search by **en** returns nothing

Comment: What is the DEFAULT Name?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want the lang returned when it's not null, and the name returned when it is, or name returned everytime?  Also how can it return a name if record doesn't exist?... None of the solutions provided only return name, which is what your query is doing...  I guess I need to see expected results when each type is used... and sample data to truly understand.

Comment: You should really add a little sqlfiddle (or some creation code with desired output) to clarify your needs, the answers seems to indicate that there's some confusion...

Comment: @xQbert I have added sample data

Comment: @Ilya so it's not possible to have two times `Ivan` in names, one time with `chr(0)` and another time with `ua` for example ? Name is always unique ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus name isn't unique. It possible to have `Ivan` two times

Comment: @ llya I believe @psaraj12 has provided the simplest answer that works.

Comment: @xQbert I would say no, but may be wrong : this will return two rows if theres's `Ivan / en` and `Ivan / chr(0)`. I think that in this case, only one value should be returned. But with a distinct (if only Name is needed, this would be ok).

Comment: See this sqlFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1843a1/8 to see what's op wants (first query) and what the different answers return.

Comment: @Raphael if the input of language in a particular order is important then i agree

Comment: @psaraj12 well, seems that I misunderstood something : you have to check ON ALL ROWS if there's any entry with given language. If that's true, DON'T RETURN the rows with only chr(0). See sample 2 => Don't return Kris.

Comment: @Raphael i understood your point with the sql fiddle ,will try to check for a solution for case 2

Answer (score 3):

Use the decode function to achieve the same

```
WITH language as 
(select count(1) lang_count from names where lang=:lang)
 SELECT 
 A.NAME 
 FROM NAMES a,language 
 where a.lang=decode(language.lang_count,0,chr(0),:lang);
```

**UPDATE 1**:-Edited the answer to solve the second case mentioned by OP.The result is same as the one tried by OP but may be little clear

Comment: Isn't chr(0) just NULL in Oracle? Decode could be an alternative, but why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @LalitKumarB: No, it is NOT the same as NULL. Please read the docs before jumping to conclusions. :-)

Comment: @toddlermenot, I might be incorect per you. Could you please show how. I might learn something new and get back to docs. Been a long time indeed.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Just execute these two queries and observe the result ( chr(0) is NOT treated like NULL ):  SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CHR(0)=CHR(0); select * from dual where null=null;

Comment: NULL = NULL is simply undetermined state. A third state perhaps? It is an incorrect comparision.

Comment: Precisely. Per your statement, both queries should yield the same results which it doesn't.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about NULL value or the ASCII? Because I am advocating over zero length string and NOT ASCII of it.

Comment: This query will return lang-specific and default rows. (e.g. for 2-nd case from my question, it will return `Mike` and `Kris`)

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I do not know if the recent series of downvotes of my answers is you. But if it is you, I would say that it is uncalled for, despite never downvoting your *wrong* (now deleted) answer. This is not cool and goes against the philosophy of the SO community dude. Be nice.

Comment: @toddlermenot, I am only aware of the downvote on my answer, which I later deleted, since I was unable to explain further and found it better to stop further discussion as it was going directionless. I don't think I participated in any other discussions to up/down vote your answers.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Really? SO's vote abuse reversal script has given all my lost points(-20) back and your number of downvotes happen to reduce from 23 yesterday to 13 today(-10) coincidentally? Grow up. How on earth did they made you a moderator at orafaq? And please stop with "I am here to learn" facade. All you seem to like is hide your mistakes and take vengeance on people who point out your mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should be faster:

```
SELECT name FROM
(
   SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN lang = :lang  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS rn
   FROM names WHERE lang = :lang OR lang = chr(0)   
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: If I am not blind, but it is an overkill. Either `NVL` or even `DECODE` for that matter should suffice the requirement.

Comment: @ Lalit Kumar B: You're right, I'm just used to `CASE`. I don't think it's gonna be a big difference between `case`/`nvl`/`decode` though in this case.

Comment: I would always recommend using `CASE` as opposed to `NVL()` and `DECODE()` @Lalit; [they implicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13712763/458741) [convert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions119.htm#SQLRF00684) datatypes, whereas `CASE` and `COALESCE()` don't. I've been caught out a couple of times by this now and it's easier to use the ANSI functions.