# Should I use DECODE or CASE in Cognos 10 Report Studio Expressions?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, cognos-10

I'd like to take a date stored as something like *201609* and display something like **Fall 2016** as an Expression in Cognos Report Studio (Cognos 10).

I really only need to check the months 01, 05, and 09 for Winter, Spring, and Fall.

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712763/are-a-case-statement-and-a-decode-equivalent/) about `case` and `decode` and I'm converting old Cognos7 reports to Cognos 10 Report Studio. I've also read the documentation for the `case` statement for being used inside a `Select` clause but I don't see any examples of how to write it as an expression in a calculated column or even as a Singleton (most likely use for what I'm looking for).

The way I've converted the old technique from Cognos7 to Cognos 10 Report studio is something like:

```
 CONCAT(CONCAT(DECODE(SUBSTR([TermDate],5 ,2),'09','Fall' ,'01','Winter','Spring')
 , ' ') , SUBSTR([TermDate],1 ,4))
```

I'd be very interested in how to do this in a more efficient, up-to-date method in Cognos 10 Report Studio and whether `CASE` is what I need to use in Expression fields.

Comment: You might want to convert `[this question]` into a link to the question you're referring to :-)

Comment: `SUBSTR([TermDate],..)` is invalid SQL for Oracle. Is `[TermDate]` something that is replaced by Cognos?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's a Field Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more minutes, I realized I was on the right track. Here is an approximate solution.

The following expression can be entered into an Expression field in Cognos 10 Report Studio either as a calculated column or as a Singleton.

```
CASE SUBSTR([TermDate],5 ,2) WHEN '09' THEN 'Fall'
WHEN '01' THEN 'Winter'
WHEN '05' THEN 'Spring'
END || ' ' || SUBSTR([TermDate], 1, 4)
```