# If column equals

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table below.
I need when indicator = 0 then date = null

I have tried a case statement but receive errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     Select 
       Case when a.indicator = 0
          Then a.date = 0
             Else a.date
                End Date

      From TableA a
```

TableA

```
   Id         Date     Indicator
    1          1/1/17      0
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

`SELECT CASE WHEN a.indicator = 0 THEN NULL ELSE a.date END AS 'Date' FROM TableA AS a`

The reason `a.date = 0` (or `date = null`) is wrong is that you are not assigning a new value to `a.date` but rather stating what value (`null`) should be returned from the case expression when it is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  decode(a.indicator, 0, null, a.date) date
from
  tableA
```

Comment: [Don't use `DECODE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716116/458741) it's not ANSII standard and there's a few gotchas. It's best to prefer CASE

Answer (score 0):

Use this select :

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN A.INDICATOR = 0 THEN 
    NULL
  ELSE A.DATE
END DATE
FROM TABLEA A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
Select "Id", 
    Case 
        when "Indicator" <> 0 
            Then "Date" End AS Date1, 
    "Indicator"
From TableA;
```

Please notice I have reversed your logic and skipped the `else null` because this is anyway default if not used.

More about case: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4efe8a/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    Case a.indicator when 0
        Then null
            Else a.date
            End
 From TableA a
```