# Incompatible datatype in union on Oracle

Tags: oracle, union

Folks!

Our ORM (Entity Framework) in conjunction to our Oracle Provider (Devart) is generating some SQL that Oracle is unable to execute. I'm not sure who causes the problem, perhaps Devart generates an SQL that can be run given that we have the environment set up.

There's two possibilities I can think of:

- Devart generates garbage;
- Oracle is not set up properly.

I think it would be rather difficult to provide Devart with a sample so that they could run into the same situation (I've asked them [here](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=27374)) so let's see the second one.

Code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT        TO_CHAR(NULL) AS EXPR2
FROM            SYS.DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT        TO_NUMBER(NULL) AS EXPR2
FROM            SYS.DUAL DUAL_1
```

Code that works:

```
SELECT        TO_NUMBER(NULL) AS EXPR2
FROM            SYS.DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT        TO_CHAR(NULL) AS EXPR2
FROM            SYS.DUAL DUAL_1
```

As can be seen, Oracle does accept different types if the first select brings a number column. But our provider generates the inverse situation (first char then number).

And the question: There's any setting we need to do in Oracle to accept the first sql sample?

Unfortunately we don't know what generates this pattern but in case you'd like to try, our linq is [here](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=27374).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two statements. Copy and paste error?

Comment: "Unable to execute" is a rather vague description of the problem.  I'm assuming that the problem is that you get an error of some sort.  If so, posting the error (the Oracle error number and the text of the message) is likely to be helpful.  I'm guessing that you are implying that you're getting an "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression" error...

Comment: Please provide the exact error codes.

Comment: @Werlang . . . I modified the question after testing the code on SQL Fiddle.  The number-first version works; the character-first does not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name take a closer look

Comment: @Werlang: now that it was edited - there is a difference ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting to be changed in order to let it works. Please read the answer[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057748/union-clause-in-sql) where Ben perfectly answered how it works.

Comment: I'll accept it as answer because if there's nothing we can do in Oracle we'll have to sort it out with Devart. Tnx